# buy bitcoin or bitcoin cash?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, buy-bitcoins, coinbase.com

I have some bitcoins on coinbase and was going to buy more.

But now I see bitcoin cash available on coinbase.

Should I buy bitcoins or bitcoin cash? What is difference? And they have the same price?

**UPDATE**: They have different price, so it looks like new cryptocurrency.

Comment: What do you think inside? What are your arguments for the one or the other? (I'm curious, just asking)

Comment: @Basj, what do you mean "inside"? I don't have any arguments yet, need to do some research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin cash, is centralized, and it is difficult to run a full node of it, and it does not have a great developer strenth.

Bitcoin (the original) have many developers developing new tecnologies like the lighning tecnology. And it is fully descentralized. But the mempool is crowded right now wich makes the fees quite high.

I think in the short term Bcash (Bitcoin cash, nickname) will be more usable, with lower fees, but in the long term in cannot compete with Bitcoin.

Comment: BCash is a completely different cryptocurrency by Brazilians, do not use it as a name for Bitcoin Cash. It is usually used in a derogative way to remove the word Bitcoin from Bitcoin Cash.